# How can I stream video with authentication using NodeJS/HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, video

I have this route on my backend:

```
const { id } = req.params
        if (!id) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Invalid request' })

        const videoPath = `videos/${id}.mp4`
        const videoStat = fs.statSync(videoPath)
        const fileSize = videoStat.size
        const videoRange = req.headers.range

        if (videoRange) {

            const parts = videoRange.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            const end = parts[1]
                ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
                : fileSize - 1;
            const chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
            const file = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
            const header = {
                'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                'Content-Length': chunksize,
                'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            };
            res.writeHead(206, header);
            file.pipe(res);

        } else {

            const head = {
                'Content-Length': fileSize,
                'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            };
            res.writeHead(200, head);
            fs.createReadStream(videoPath).pipe(res)

        }
```

I already have a middleware to detect if the user is authenticated or not. It works fine, but I don't really know how to implement it on the front-end. I was trying something like this:

```
<video crossOrigin="anonymous" id="videoPlayer" controls>
                    <source src={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + '/v1/video/get/' + props.videoId} type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
```

But it doesn't really work, since the request is going without the token. What could I do to make the front-end request authenticated using the token from cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using crossOrigin="use-credentials" and then on the backend, instead of reading the token from the headers in this specific case, im getting the token from the cookies.